# CRM 4.0 - Create Method Cloning Quote Record

Tags: javascript, crm, dynamics-crm-4

Can anyone help me please?

I'm trying to create a record using the create method through javascript. 
I need to copy all the fields' value and create a new entity. Like cloning a record in CRM 4.0

I'm using quote entity. I'm trying to pass the Opportunity. It was successful but when i look into the grid view, the opportunity field is blank. but in the form, it has a value.

Then i try to look into the opportunity form and see related Quotation, but it doesn't appear there.

Thank you for your reply. here's my code

```html
>     
 var authenticationHeader = GenerateAuthenticationHeader();
 var OpportunityID = crmForm.all.opportunityid.DataValue[0].id;  
 var varFields = "<opportunityid>"+ OpportunityID +"</opportunityid>"

 var xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" + 
 "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'"+
 " xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'"+
 " xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>"+ 
 authenticationHeader+
 "<soap:Body>"+ 
 "<Create xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices'>"+ 
 "<entity xsi:type='quote'>"+ 
 varFields + 
 "</entity>"+ 
 "</Create>"+ 
 "</soap:Body>"+ 
 "</soap:Envelope>";
 // Prepare the xmlHttpObject and send the request.
 var xHReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
 xHReq.Open("POST", "/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx", false);
 xHReq.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction","http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/Create");
 xHReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
 xHReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", xml.length);
 xHReq.send(xml);
 // Capture the result
 var resultXml = xHReq.responseXML;

 // Check for errors.
 var errorCount = resultXml.selectNodes('//error').length;
 if (errorCount != 0)
 {
  var msg = resultXml.selectSingleNode('//description').nodeTypedValue;
  alert(msg);
 }
 // Open new contact record if no errors.
 else
 {
    var quoteid = resultXml.selectSingleNode("//CreateResult");
    window.open("/sfa/quotes/edit.aspx?id={"+quoteid.nodeTypedValue+"}");
 }
}
```

Kindly help me please. 
I really need it badly.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you post some code? I guess that would help people help towards a solution.

Comment: Hi Erwin,

I have added the code already on my question. thank you.

Comment: Personally I have seen these kind of CRM Dynamics solutions before at customers of mine and they all left a bad taste in my mouth. I don't know the exact solution for your problem but I strongly advice to go back to the drawing board and really think this solution ten times over.